# How do I send messages from Javascript to Java?

Tags: java, javascript, safari, applet

I'm kind of stuck because I can get JavaScript to send a message to a Java applet. I can get it to work the other way round. Does anyone know a proper way to do this that works everywhere?

Comment: So what have you done (with source code)? What browsers is it failing on? Have you followed the instructions here: http://devedge-temp.mozilla.org/library/manuals/2000/javascript/1.3/guide/lc.html

Comment: http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/guide/plugin/developer_guide/js_java.html#how

Comment: I only use Safari right now. And i've looked at both documents

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may need to add `<PARAM NAME="scriptable" VALUE="true">` to the `OBJECT` or `APPLET` tag.

Answer (score 2):

For calling Java from JavaScript, you can have public methods in your applet that you call from JavaScript. See [this post](http://jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=16833) for more information.

For calling JavaScript from Java, you use [JSObject](http://java.sun.com/products/plugin/1.3/docs/jsobject.html).